# What media type should I use in Responsive Web Design?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive-design

I see some using "only screen" in the media queries, others using "all", others using "screen and print", others using "screen"(without the "only"), others don't specify the media type.

I don't intend to use specific CSS for printing or other medias. Should I use "only screen". Should I not specify the media type?

What media type most people are using and why?

Comment: Responsive web design has no standard and is not a standard. It's just the cool thing to do these days.

Comment: @BoltClock but what media type most people are using and why?

Comment: There is no media type, just like there's no media type for "web 2.0"

Comment: @Diodeus: [Media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Comment: OK, I should have said there is no "special" media type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically:

- Either use `media="screen"` for applying your main stylesheet to all browsers, or just leave out the `media` attribute altogether if you don't care about print
- Use `media="print"` for applying your print stylesheet if you do care about print
- If you'd like, include the `only` keyword only for media queries like `screen and (max-width: 1000px)` for your responsive styles (there isn't any right, wrong or standard to follow here)

The `only` keyword was introduced mainly to stop older browsers from applying stylesheets intended for other devices, like modern browsers on smartphones and tablet computers. See [the Media Queries spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries).

**Do not** use `media="only screen"` for your main stylesheet. If you do, IE8 and older will completely ignore your main stylesheet, and your site will appear unstyled in those versions.

---

For some background: [the HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.13) asks that media "types" (or *media descriptors*) like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1000px)" href="resp.css">
```

Should be parsed with the `and ...` part ignored, so it would be equivalent to this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="resp.css">
```

Meaning it would apply in older browsers that don't support CSS3 media queries, but *do* fully support CSS2 media types. This may cause unwanted side effects, e.g. a mobile stylesheet being applied in older desktop browsers.

In my experience, however, this has never happened; as far as I'm aware, IE7 and IE8 simply treat `screen and (max-width: 1000px)` as an invalid media descriptor and ignore that stylesheet altogether.

But I like to be on the safe side, and put the `only` keyword in media queries intended specifically for use by modern browsers.

Of course, this rule has been changed in HTML5 in order to be compatible with media queries in CSS3. It just won't apply to older browsers that were released before work on HTML5 began.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's easier and better performance to put all the styles into a single stylesheet:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="style.css">
```

Then you can override as you go up:

```
/* put mobile-friendly first (before media queries) */ 

@media screen and (min-width:481px) {
    /* ... */
}

@media screen and (min-width:961px) {
    /* ... */
}

@media print {
    /* print-specific overrides */ 
}
```

Checkout [H5BP](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and [320 and up](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/).

You can use `screen` or `all`. If you're adding things like background images that only apply to screens, then it definitely makes sense to use `screen`. For real basic stuff it doesn't matter much.